# Can I start entering the text in UITextFiled at specific position in IOS ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to start entering the text in UITextFiled at specific position ?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Leaving some certain blank space in textfield or you want your cursor to start on a specific position and not at the end? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a class using subclass of UITextField and in .m file

```
 #import "CustomTextField.h"
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 @implementation CustomTextField


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
 {
  self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

  if (self) {

  //self.clipsToBounds = YES;
  //[self setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];

   self.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,15,46)];
   self.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }

  return self;

 }
```

Go to your storyboard or xib and click on identity inspector and replace UITextfield with your own "CustomTextField" in class option.

Comment: It is working like charm Appreciable code Anuj Kumar Rai Thanks a lot